# selecting tr's using data

Tags: jquery, dataset

I have a table whose rows have year data. I want to select the rows with the given year.

```
<tr data-year="1964"><td></td></tr>
<tr data-year="1964"><td></td></tr>
<tr data-year="1964"><td></td></tr>
<tr data-year="1965"><td></td></tr>
<tr data-year="1965"><td></td></tr>
<tr data-year="1965"><td></td></tr>
etc.
```

Using jQuery: I want to select only rows where data-year is 1964.

Obviously, this does not work:

```js
var year = 1964;
console.log( $("tr").data('year').eq(year) ); // cannot read eq of undefined
```

I've tried some other ways but none work.

Answer (score 0):

You could possibly do:

```
$('tr[data-year=1964]')
​
// Browser console output:
0: <tr data-year="1964">​
1: <tr data-year="1964">​
2: <tr data-year="1964">
​
length: 3
```

So to use that with the variable:

```
var year = 1964;

$('tr[data-year=' + year + ']')
```

Comment: Or, without jquery: `document.querySelectorAll('tr[data-year=' + year + ']');`